# autodesk-model-derivative 401 Invalid authorization header

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am trying to use autodesk's model derivative api to read metadata of revit files. To do so, it needs to convert revit file to svf format. I'm trying to use   https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job endpoint to do so following official example here https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-metadata-from-source-file/. I used same authorization header for creating bucket, uploading file. It has data:creat, data:read, data:write.
So I'm not sure why it didn't work for the job endpoint. Is this because I don't have access to model derivative apis?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that **Model Derivative API** is enabled for your **Forge app** on the [My Apps](https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps) website

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I double checked that, and I do have Model Derivative API selected! Is there any other potential problems that I may missed? Thanks a lot!

Comment: So I think it might also be the urn I sent is problematic. so for example if the object_id return by get object details is 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:designtest_dataderivative/file.rvt'. Should I do base64 encoding over 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:designtest_dataderivative' or 'adsk.objects:os.object:designtest_dataderivative' or 'urn:adsk.objects:os.object:designtest_dataderivative/file.rvt'? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please provide the full reply you get when running the curl command? It could provide useful info. Otherwise it looks like you might have added an extra space or other character for the "Authorization" header value: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/401-unauthorized-403-forbidden
Can you double-check that as well?

Comment: The article you're following shows what the raw urn looks like (i.e. what you have to encode) and then what it should look like after the encoding. 
If it's correctly encoded it will always start with "dX..."

Comment: Hi, thanks, it was because the urn I used was not including the file name. it needs to be the objectid. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that urn should be objectid which also includes the file name.